# How to config headers in axios on Laravel application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to build a small application on `Vuejs 2.0` where I'm having axios call and in configuration I'm setting the headers something like this:

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'http://www.conxn.co.in',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

And calling the url something like this:

```
axios.post('http://www.conxn.co.in/CoxnsvcA.svc/Login', postData,{headers: getLoginHeader()})
```

But I can see the origin is not changed from local host:

[image: screenshot]

Guide me how can I set the Origin to the url as mentioned.

Thanks

Comment: why are you calling `getLoginHeader()` why not just pass the headers?

Comment: @samayo I'm simply trying to keep my code little clean, I'm importing the same and calling the function,headers are working fine if I have `localhost` apis but for different url, I'm getting the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how CORS works. You cannot modify the origin header being sent out because that's set by the browser for security purposes. The server needs to allow the request by returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It doesn't look like the server you're requesting ajax from is setup correctly for CORS requests.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just have one doubt, are you talking about the server which is generating ajax request or about the server which is receiving request.

Comment: The server receiving the request needs to grant CORS access using the CORS headers, that tells the browser that the request coming from site A is okay to send to site B.